# Codeigniter - Re-sizing multiple images works, but wrong sizes?

Tags: image, codeigniter, resize

I'm trying to resize a fullsize image poster into three smaller variants of the file. I first save the fullsize poster, then i use it's path to create the smaller ones. The problem is that the sizes are incorrect. I have a $conf array containing general config info for all images, and then i have a $conf array for each image with specific changes (eg. size). I clear the lib before every new init.

```
// Config for all images
$conf['source_image'] = $file_path;
$conf['quality'] = 80;
$conf['maintain_ratio'] = true;
$conf['master_dim'] = 'auto';

// Small
$conf['new_image'] = 'img/movie_images/posters_small/' . $file_name;
$conf['height'] = 75;
//$conf['width'] = 55;

$this->image_lib->initialize($conf);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
//unset($conf['width']);

// Medium
$conf['new_image'] = 'img/movie_images/posters_medium/' . $file_name;
$conf['height'] = 200;

$this->image_lib->initialize($conf);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();

// Big
$conf['new_image'] = 'img/movie_images/posters_big/' . $file_name;
$conf['height'] = 300;

$this->image_lib->initialize($conf);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

See any errors in the code? I tried outputting errors as someone advised in another question here, but that didn't show anything either. I don't understand how it works really. If i set "master_dim" to auto, the first (the small) image get's the right height, but the default width (which is really really wide). If i set master_dim to "width", the small image stays the same (really wide, but correct height). If i set master_dim to "height" they all get the correct height, but the small one still is super wide.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the code i tried playing around with the width of the small image to get it's correct size, but didn't get it to work.

After setting master_dim to height, and also setting the width of the small image manually, it works as i want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image library from http://thephpcode.com/blog/codeigniter/gradient-image-library-for-codeigniter to convert the image to fit in to a correct width and size.